# Same query, with or without condition.

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a query that selects rows by condition, but if there is no response for that condition, the code should select the same columns, but without the condition.

What the right way to do this? Thanks!

This is my example - select this:

```
select top 1 * 
from tbl 
where isActive = 1
```

but if there is no response, select this instead:

```
select top 1 * 
from tbl
```

Note that the query is big and complex, so I prefer not to select one and then select the second one, if the first one is null. Also because I have a `union` after this and it throws an error with this syntax.

Comment: If there's always top 1, then just use `order by isActive desc`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your query is a `select top x ...` query I would simply use the order by as suggested by Peter's answer. Assuming it's not involving `top x`, since you wrote your actual query is big and complicated, you can use a common table expression.
The idea is that you encapsulate the big and complex query inside the cte, but instead of writing the where clause to filter out records, you use a case expression to return 1 or 0 if the condition is true or false for each record.

Then you select from that cte where either the case expression results with 1 or there are no records in the cte where the case expression results with 1.

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    IsActive bit
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1),(1),(NULL),(1),(1),(NULL),
(1),(1),(NULL),(1),(1),(NULL),
(1),(1),(NULL),(1),(1),(NULL),
(1),(1),(NULL),(1),(1),(NULL)
```

The common table expression:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  Id, IsActive, 
            CASE WHEN IsActive = 1 THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
            END As FoundRecords
    FROM @T
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT Id, IsActive
FROM CTE
WHERE FoundRecords = 1
OR NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM CTE
    WHERE FoundRecords = 1
)
```

Results:

```
Id  IsActive
1   True
2   True
4   True
5   True
7   True
8   True
10  True
11  True
13  True
14  True
16  True
17  True
19  True
20  True
22  True
23  True
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/XEZIJW26108)

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to not use `where isActive = 1` but instead order by `isActive` in descending order:

```
select top 1 *
from tbl
order by isActive desc
```

You might even want to consider adding additional ordering fields (e.g. id, name, date), because without that the resulting item could be unpredictable.

Comment: If satisfied, don't forget to upvote and/or mark an answer as 'the' accepted answer (mine or some other)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IF-Else condition, right?

```
DECLARE @result INT 
SET @result = CONVERT(INT, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE isActive = 1))

IF (@result > 0)
    BEGIN
        select top 1 * from tbl where isActive = 1;
    END  
ELSE
    BEGIN
        select top 1 * from tbl;
    END
```

Comment: Welcome, You could write this query using 4 lines by removing Declare, Set, Begin & End if you want.